# When did people start putting anime characters on vehicles?

Tags: culture, itasha

I occasionally see forum posts of people in Japan showing off their anime-styled cars and I saw some whilst in Japan also. I believe there's also groups of these people who have meetups and such.

[image]
[image]

It's not just cars either, I've seen some boats and a few helicopters decorated too.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Obviously, these weren't around in the early days of anime - but when did they start appearing on the streets?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These type of otaku-owned car are called [Itasha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itasha) 痛車?, literally *"painful car"* (painfully embarrassing / painful for the wallet) and started with decoration of cars in the **80s** when Japan experienced a lot of growth and many wealthy people started importing many luxury cars. This decoration only really consisted of plushies, stickers and non-permanent features.

According to Wikipedia, fully-fledged Itasha only really started being seen in the **21st century** - when internet culture gave the anime industry a large growth sprurt - in advertising, greater fan communities and distribution.

[Expert from Itasha article, Otaku USA Magazine, **2009**](https://web.archive.org/web/20110718225635/http://www.otakuusamagazine.com/Events/Public/News1/Itasha_and_Intansha_1117.aspx)

> Most often, stickers are put on the hood and doors of the car and then airbrushed. People who think, "It's kind of embarrassing, but I really want to ride in an itasha! ... But I'd have to hide it from my family and at my job. [..] can quickly take the design off by attaching and detaching magnetic stickers.
>
> Although printing cutting sheets of personal favorite characters and putting them on the car is a popular method, people who are really devoted will commission a specialist to airbrush their designs.

This article mentions a few owners with itasha cars from **2002**.

**Notable Dates:**

- In **2007**, the first Autosalone (itasha convention) was held.
- June **2008**, Aoshima Bunka Kyozai launched "ITASHA" as one of the first offically licensed Itasha.

It's not a purely-japanese phenomenon either, there are itasha to be seen in [Malaysia](https://forum.lowyat.net/topic/1734133) , Taiwan and the Philippines too. It hasn't become overly popular in the West just yet however.